# Mantra , Stotras for Happiness, Ananda?

Tags: mantras, shloka, stotra

Mantras Similar to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-h-u-qfvTyc

Are there anything in Hinduism to be in Happy State as much as posible..

Comment: Ananda is the state of Self aka Sat Chid Ananda. Hence, modern Hindu monks use the name Ananda in their names like Vivekananda, Yogananda etc., Happiness is not in Mantras or Strotras but in the Bhakt himself, listening to mantras/stotras wont result in ananda for animals or atheists because of devolved level in spirituality.